# I can't embed iframes to make courses in the Appmaker training hub template

Tags: iframe, google-app-maker, google-workspace

I've been playing with the training hub template. I've installed it, deployed it. Everything works.

I just can't successfully create any new courses usings Google docs/slides. I publish them to the web, grab the embedded `iframe` code, chuck that in and it just seems to break when I view the course.

This is how it displays:

and this is the iframe I'm copying from my published doc:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQ6PBb1PToXsfLtX9cAxC3KpCGQwdp0HLKZi5-DG2wVAPkmWa-VPvFzn-ZuYMMl5t_D5xqTK9ZtytQE/embed?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

I've tried it without `frameboarder= width= height=` etc.... just the most basic `iframe` and it still throws the same error.

I'm not convinced it's a permission issue as it's accessible on the internet. Obviously this isn't ideal or long term but has made it easy to rule out permission issues.

I can confirm the `iframe` works if it is embedded into a Google site or used else where.

What am I doing wrong?

It throws the

> "frameborder="0" class="content-iframe">

error whether that is in the `iframe` or not:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to check off `Allow app to be embedded in any site with an iFrame` in the App Settings section.

[image: allow embedding]